# Switching regulator high frequency ripple

Tags: noise, switching-regulator, ripple

I've built a switching power supply with a TI 16006Y IC. It seems to be doing its job correctly however I'm having trouble getting rid of the high frequency ripple that occurs for a short period every time the power supply switches on. The white reference was with a different set of output capacitors. The current output bypass capacitors are (2) 47uF tantalum caps and a 0.1uF cap all in parallel which seems to be doing ok with getting rid of the low frequency oscillations. But the high frequency spikes are still there.
Any advice would be helpful. 
[image: ripple]
[image: ripple2]

Comment: What to do depends some on whether your switching regulator is performing as specified in your application. You should compare the output with the specified ripple.

Comment: By specified ripple are you referring to the datasheet specs or something else?

Comment: at high enough freqs, your caps become inductive. zoom in with your scope.

Comment: The white appears to have > 1MHz burst between 20kHz sawtooth. What impedance are your caps at this f and how much current*ESR of caps accounts for this.

Comment: I zoomed in and added another picture

Comment: For some reason I have a hard time finding caps that have their esr charts published

Comment: I have a hard time understand why you think we should know your BOM parts list, schematic and layout which are need to analyze your issues.. If you did not see an ESR published , it's because it is a general purpose one and you chose the wrong part.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why you need a bom and schematic to know what noise and ripple is.

Comment: If you want help, there is a minimum set of specs and info needed. Obviously you have no specs or understanding why you have noise. Fixing noise can create instability, so please provide details. Acceptance criteria, design details

Comment: I have no problem providing more information. But I do have a hard time finding caps with published esr. Guidance would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90236/discussion-between-sunnyskyguy-ee75-and-steven-lutz).

Comment: good luck finding help

Comment: Im.having trouble loading chat on my mobile device.

Comment: Yes this is my first power supply design. I followed the datasheet pretty close although samples there were based in the 5v version of the IC rather than my 3.3v version.

Comment: There are tantalum devices specifically designed with low ESR. That said, I would not be using tantalums on a SMPS design that has a switching frequency of 2.1MHz (and much higher switching edge rates). Ceramics would be a better choice here in my view.

Comment: Can you explain why low esr is a bad thing? I thought it was desirable.